# Dealing with KeyEvents in java

Tags: java, keylistener

Say I have a GUI, and I want the program to actually run when the spacebar is pressed, but if the spacebar is pressed again then I want the program to exit. Would something like this work?

```
public class MouseClicker extends JApplet implements KeyListener{
int counter = 0;
MouseClicker m1 = new MouseClicker();

//all of the other methods

public void keyPressed( KeyEvent e) {
int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
if(keyCode==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
 m1.click();
 counter ++;
 if(counter%2==0)
  System.exit(0);
}
//other methods needed for KeyListener
}
```

Comment: Note that counter really must be volatile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it and see ;-)

Seriously though, what do you mean you want to program to run when the space bar is pressed? Unless the program is already running, how are you going to receive the `KeyEvent`?

As for the other half of your question, the code you have should, in general, make Java exit when the space bar is pressed. Note that there's no point in using a counter, since as soon as Java exits, the value of the counter is lost. Also note that `JApplet` is an exception to the "in general"... you normally can't call `System.exit` from an applet, because the applet runs under the control of a browser and Java is only supposed to exit when the user closes the browser, not whenever your applet is done. There could be other applets running in the same JVM and they might not be done with what they're doing yet.

Comment: I worded my question terribly, sorry about that. By running I meant to run the click() method which would continue to click the same area over and over again with time intervals between the clicks until the spacebar was pressed. That would require threads, correct?

Comment: Also, I meant for this program not to be in a webpage, but instead be an application. Java is my only language, and the only way I know of doing this is running the program straight from the compiler. Is there a way to have the program run as an app?

Comment: Yes; you start it with a public static void main(String[] args) method, and you'd use a JFrame instead of a JApplet as the container for your GUI. Ask another question if you need more detail on that point.

Comment: For the thing about clicking repeatedly, yes you would need to use threads, but Java probably has something that can handle the threading for you. But again, that's a matter for another question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, I think the AWT code is correct but the rest is terribly cryptic (Not that I don't understand it, but it doesn't express what you are actually doing very well, does it?)

How about:

```
boolean running=false;

...
if(running)
    System.exit(0);
else
    running=true;
```

instead?

Update:
After reading your discussion on the other post, you are going to have a little strangeness.

There is this concept of the AWT thread.  Everything done with the AWT must be done on that thread.  So when the space bar is pressed, you will get that event on the AWT thread.  You probably don't want to keep it though because as long as you hold onto it, it will prevent other graphics updates.

I suggest looking at SwingTimer Set a swing timer to notify you every few ms, and that notification will come in on the AWT thread so that you can use it to click your button, then just exit and wait for the next timer event.

When they press space bar again, system.exit() should work fine.

Comment: Is running a predefined boolean value in java?

Comment: No, the first line of code got appended to my how about: text.